# iPhone -- getting the adjusted font size of a UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, font-size

I have a UITextField with the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property set to YES.  I want to get ahold of the current (adjusted) font size.  Is that possible?

If not, getting ahold of the actual width of the text (in the adjusted size) would be almost as good.

Answer (score 1):

In the adjusted size, the width of the text would be the same as the width of the text field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but it should not be too difficult to write your own class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small snippet/extension I wrote down to handle this.

http://swiftstub.com/134886004/